# Google Maps generates but does not display

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have maps generating (i see the code in the console) but it doesn't actually show anything on Chrome. It displays in FF but it looks terrible.

I've made sure the set the CSS like is recommended but I may have missed something:

CSS:

```
#maps{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<details id='geoLocation'>
        <summary>Find Us</summary>
        <div id='maps'></div>
</details>
```

JS:

```
function getLocation(){
    var geoConfig = {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 60000, timeout: 100000}
    var distance = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showInfo,showError, geoConfig);
}
function showInfo(position){
   maps(position);
}
function showError(e){
    if (e.code == 2){
          alert("Position unavailable");
    }else{
         alert("Other error");
    }
}

function maps(position){
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
       center: location,
       zoom: 12,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'), mapOptions);

    var markerOptions = {
       position: location,
       map: map
   };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    marker.setMap(map);

   distance = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((position.coords.latitude-45),2)+Math.pow((position.coords.longitude-75),2)))*79;
    var infoWindowOptions = {content: 'Distance to Store = ' + distance};

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(e){

     infoWindow.open(map, marker);

   });
}
```

Comment: I usually also specify something like this in my CSS on any map page, `html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }`

Comment: OT, but you don't need to call `marker.setMap(map);` as you already specified `map: map` in your markerOptions

Comment: Hey I got it to show up by giving it an actual height, like 300px or something and a width of 100%. Now Im just trying to get an info bubble to show up.